# Generate on/off signals of random duration SIMULINK

Tags: events, simulink, exponential-distribution

For my SIMULINK model I need to generate a signal that takes the values 1 or 0. To generate it I need to draw a number from a an exponential distribution and use this number as the time the signal stays in 0. Once this time has passed, I have to draw a new number from the exponential distribution and use this number as the time the signal stays in 1, and the repeat the process until the end of the simulation. As a SIMULINK newbie I'm quite puzzled by this problem and would appreciate any suggestions on how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a couple of choices.

In MATLAB, you can generate all samples in advance (i.e. before running the simulation) and use them to create a suitable signal, then use that as an input into the model (using the [From Workspace](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/fromworkspace.html) block).

Or, if you need to do the sampling at each time step, then you have to write an S-Function, using the random number in the [mdlGetTimeOfNextVarHit](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/mdlgettimeofnextvarhit.html) method.  There is an example of doing something very similar on the [Goddard Consulting](http://www.goddardconsulting.ca) web site called [Square Wave with Jitter](http://www.goddardconsulting.ca/simulink-sfunction-square-wave-with-jitter.html).